# Over 10 second Time to First Byte on homepage?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, performance

Ok so I'm running CE 1.9.1.0 with maybe 3-4 extensions and around 25k products & 25 categories.

As the title suggests my TTFB on the home page is EXTREMELY slow, around 10-12 seconds on average. It's so bad that I installed a Full Page Cache plugin to hide how slow it really is, but I'm still very curious as to why this is the case ..

I'm using a dedicated server with Nexcess (who I presume is very good with Magento stores) and every asset is optimized (gzip, minified assets, flat category/products enabled, etc.) yet the TTFB time is so long, without the caching plugin.

Why can this happen? I feel like something is **very** wrong I just can't debug it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: it is unlikely nexcess optimized your store, in particular, especially that list with gzip etc, lol, this is your primary task, not their ... install aoe_profiler, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a demo store with sample data - test the performance on that. You need a neutral to rule out your environment.

If the demo store is fine - you need to crack open the Magento profiler and start isolating the bottleneck. Following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) in terms of module disabling is a crude/quick way to isolate module bottlenecks.

Shouldn't take more than a few minutes to find and fix.

Comment: Thank you -- I do have a couple of demo stores on the same server and it doesn't have the TTFB issue so I know it's likely an extension ... just sucks because the extensions we're using are all needed right now. Very nice answer/link, thank you, I will take a look.